# Gap appears between header and cell when resize tableview header height in scrollViewDidScroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

Originally the headerView's size is the same as the screen bound's size, and the first cell's top aligns with the headerView's bottom.  I tried to resize the `UITableView` `headerView` height in the `scrollViewDidScorll` method, but there was a gap appearing when I scrolled. It seems there are some default constraints between the headerView and the cell.

I have changed the background color of my header view to blue, and print out the height after I scroll down. It seems the header view's height is updated correctly, but the gap enlarged as my headerView height becomes smaller.

[image]

Here is my code snippet

```
class ProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundContainerView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var overlayView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundContainerViewTopSpace: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var backgroundImageViewOriginHeight: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = self.tableView.rowHeight
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.headerView.frame.size = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
        self.backgroundImageViewOriginHeight = self.headerView.frame.size.height
    }


    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0{
            self.headerView.frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            self.headerView.frame.size.height =  self.backgroundImageViewOriginHeight - scrollView.contentOffset.y
        }else{
            self.headerView.frame.size.height =  self.backgroundImageViewOriginHeight -  scrollView.contentOffset.y
            print(self.headerView.frame.size.height)
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIden, for: indexPath) as! Mycell
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }


}
```

The header height update from the console

```
574.5
572.5
571.5
569.0
568.0
567.0
565.5
564.5
563.5
562.5
561.5
560.0
```

Any help and suggestion is welcome

Comment: it is smaller 2 times faster because you are changign height and offset so, making it smaller 2 times

Answer (score 0):

In your `scrollViewDidScroll`, under the `else`, you are not setting the `self.headerView.frame.origin.y` to `scrollView.contentOffset.y`. If you are only changing the height of the view, the views Y will remain the same, but as the contentView of the scrollview is moving, it will move up.

You will need to set `self.headerView.frame.origin.y` to `scrollView.contentOffset.y`. This will cause the view to move with the scrolling at the top of the window.

Add the line

```
self.headerView.frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y
```

in the `else` to fix this problem.

Comment: Removing the line `self.headerView.frame.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y` doesn't fix the problem. `self.headerView.frame.origin.y` only applies when the `scrollView.offset.y` less than zero, that means the user is dragging down, so I want to have a stretchy effect of the header cover. When the user is scrolling down, I  decrease the height of the header view

Comment: @KesongXie Oh I see, you'll need to set the `self.headerView.frame.origin.y` to `scrollView.contentOffset.y`, as now your views bottom moves up twice as fast (once because of scrolling, and once more because you decrease the height).